# How did Ron get hurt so much when the Queen attacked his horse?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-philosophers-stone

In the First Harry Potter Film, *[Harry Potter and The Philosopher's Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Philosopher%27s_Stone_(film))* when Ron Weasley is attempting to sacrifice himself with the Queen stabbing his horse, he falls down and passes out. But should that really hurt him enough to make him pass out?

Answer (score 8):

Well he doesn't just "fall down and pass out"....the knight he is riding is effectively blown up.

## He's thrown off quite forcibly and hits the ground *hard*.

In fact this is slightly different from the actual novel where Ron is actually struck

> He stepped forward, and the white queen pounced. She struck Ron hard across the head with her stone arm, and he crashed to the floor — Hermione screamed but stayed on her square — the white queen dragged Ron to one side. He looked as if he’d been knocked out.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Sorceror's Stone* - J.K.Rowling</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ron gets hurt so much because of 3 reasons:

1. The chess match is magic. It is meant to be a challenge, and is not meant for heroes, but villains. The chess match wants you to get hurt as much as you can.
2. The Queen collides with the knight. In the film, the Queen does not slash the knight, but instead rams into it. As the chess pieces are fragile, the knight broke into many pieces. One of those pieces might have hurt Ron by cutting him.
3. (By Paulie_D) Ron does not just fall off the knight, but the knight explodes, and Ron hits the ground hard.

Comment: An 11 year old simply falling from a horse onto a hard surface is going to be messed up pretty badly, as well, even if there is no explosive force.